# Select element by and classname in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, traversal

I have an onChange event that needs to dynamically select an ID and then add a preset classname to pass to a function.

```
onChange = "show(document.getElementById(this.value). {select a class here? } );"
```

The equivalent in jquery

```
$('#'+this.value+'.myclassname').function();
```

So how do I select an ID+classname in javascript?  I know I'm being dense.

Comment: "I know I'm being dense." made me laugh. Don't worry about sounding silly, you presented the question adequately. Why can't you just use jquery?

Comment: I don't think, from a quick Google, that there *is* an easy way to find an element by class name, sadly. I'd definitely suggest sticking with jQuery on this one.

Comment: no, that's right, you can't do it without walking the DOM. I have another question though - do you have more than one element with the same ID? You shouldn't (ever!) have that, so why not just use getElementById?

Comment: Well I guess I was asking because I was curious.  Seems like a simple enough thing to do - but Google couldn't help me and I thought maybe I just wasnt phrasing the question right.  But yeah I didn't realize I had items with the same ID and the little show function I have was obviously targeting the wrong element...but then I was thinking how do I even select an item by classname in javascript if I wanted to...

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a classname? Ids should be unique.

```
var element = document.getElementById('myId');
```

Or say `element` is a parent and you want a child with a class

```
var elements = element.getElementsByTagName('*');

var newElements = [];

for (var i = 0, length = elements.length; i < length; i++) {

    if ((' ' + elements[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' yourClassName ') > -1) {
         newElements.push(elements[i]);
    }
}
```

This code basically walks through all children, and uses `indexOf()` to test for the presence of your class. If it finds it, it pushes it onto the new array.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.anyexample.com/webdev/javascript/javascript_getelementsbyclass_function.xml

```
function getElementsByClass( searchClass, domNode, tagName) { 
    if (domNode == null) domNode = document;
    if (tagName == null) tagName = '*';
    var el = new Array();
    var tags = domNode.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
    var tcl = " "+searchClass+" ";
    for(i=0,j=0; i<tags.length; i++) { 
        var test = " " + tags[i].className + " ";
        if (test.indexOf(tcl) != -1) 
            el[j++] = tags[i];
    } 
    return el;
} 
getElementsByClass('center', document.getElementById('content'))
```