# on click add class two classes to different elements

Tags: javascript

I am building a [website](http://marekfraczyk.com/szymon) which has vertical nav on the left side and content on the right, where nav takes 20% width and content 80%.

I would like to on click (of the toggle div, inside nav) change the width of the nav to 5% and the content width to 95%.

I know how add class to .the element that is being clicked, but I have to idea how to affect the others.
Any help would be highly appreciated!

```
<div class="nav">
            <div class="toggle">
                <img src="images/toggle.png"/>
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li class="header"><p>Szymon Fraczyk<br>photography</p></li>
                <li class="szymon"><a href="index.html"><p>Szymon Fraczyk</p></a></li>
                <li class="zdjecia"><a href="index.html"><p>Zdjecia</p></a></li>
                <li class="slubne"><a href="index.html"><p>Slubne</p></a></li>
                <li class="chrzciny"><a href="index.html"><p>Chrzciny</p></a></li>
                <li class="kontakt"><a href="index.html"><p>Kontakt</p></a></li>
                <li class="kontakt"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="royalSlider rsDefault">
                <img class="rsImg" src="images/1.jpg" alt="image desc" />
                <img class="rsImg" src="images/2.jpg" alt="image desc" />
                <img class="rsImg" src="images/3.jpg" alt="image desc" />
                <img class="rsImg" src="images/4.jpg" alt="image desc" />
                <img class="rsImg" src="images/5.jpg" alt="image desc" />
                <img class="rsImg" src="images/6.jpg" alt="image desc" />
                <img class="rsImg" src="images/7.jpg" alt="image desc" />
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Do they both have a unique id? Can you show us any html/code you've tried?

Comment: each of them has a class: .nav and .content

Comment: check querySelector http://caniuse.com/#search=queryselector, they are probably gonna give you a clue, but keep in mind its ie8+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use animation and JQuery to do what you want :

Your code : **http://jsfiddle.net/f9RTJ/5/**

**I give you some nice animations effects :)**

**css :**

```
.nav {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:20%;
    background-color:#ccc;
}

.content {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    width:80%;
    background-color:#aaa;
}
```

**javascript** :

```
$('.content').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({'width':'80%'}) ;
    $('.nav').animate({'width':'20%'}) ;
}) ;

$('.nav').click(function(){
    $(this).animate({'width':'5%'}) ;
    $('.content').animate({'width':'95%'}) ;
}) ;
```

Comment: You can invert size if you want the inverse effect ;)

Comment: for animation, it's better than a violent shift.

Comment: I made a fast one because we don't have it. It's just to show the fonctionality. You can do it by float if you want.

Comment: im gonna upvote you because you tried to help, thats cool, but its not a good idea to suggest people use jquery if they dont asked for.

Comment: I agree, but there animation can justify it. But a simple `document.getByClassName(..).width = ...` whith `onclick="..."` can do the job too.

Comment: I use jQuery for royal slider eitherway, so it's alright. However, the slider wont display, if I use your code, Cyril ALFARO.

Comment: @Marek Which sliders ? Can you give us some JS code, don't forget to add the code in a ready() function or it will throw an error : $(document).ready(function() { // put code there });

Comment: @Marek if it is not resolved, copy your error there. (F12 and console on Chrome and Firefox).

Comment: Dear @CyrilALFARO, the code you posted is in a ready() function. Its the royal slider that causes an issue. Please, visit the test page again to see, as it'd be difficult to explain.

Comment: To be precise, your solution worked perfectly, its just the combination with the slider for the pictures in the content div is conflicting with your code, I guess.

Comment: @Marek If it's image go out of your container (content) just ass overflow:hidden to your content class.

Comment: I just had to re-size the container for the slider, now it seems to work smoothly. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the page, it would be easier if you added an id to the content div. Then you would be able to

```
var d = document.getElementById('content');
d.className = d.className + "wideClass";
```

Otherwise you will have to loop through all the div's and find the one with the class 'content'.  Similar to this answer:
[Select element by and classname in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887619/select-element-by-and-classname-in-javascript)

Either way, once you select the element, you can append the class that will make the width 95% as you want.