# Code only applies to first elements found, multiple elements with the same id exist

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to apply the javascript to multiple divs with the same id? At the moment it only applies it to the first found, I guess at [0]. Is it possible to loop through the divs and apply it that way?

```
<body>
        <div id="mainHolder">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/collapse1.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <p>This is a collapsible panel</p>
                <img src="images/bird.jpg" height="130"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="panelBelow">
            <p>A panel is placed below the collapsible panel, just to show that when the panel above collapses the panel below is also moved up.</p>
        </div>

        <br></br>

        <div id="mainHolder">
            <div id="header">
                <img src="images/collapse1.png" />
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                <p>This is a collapsible panel</p>
                <img src="images/bird.jpg" height="130"/>
            </div>
        </div>


    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var header = null;
        var content = null;
        var mainHolder = null;
        var expandCollapseBtn = null;
        var heightValue = 0;

        header = document.getElementById("header");
        content = document.getElementById("content");
        mainHolder = document.getElementById("mainHolder");
        expandCollapseBtn = header.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

        heightValue = mainHolder.offsetHeight;

        header.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
        mainHolder.addEventListener('webkitTransitionEnd',transitionEndHandler,false);

        function handleClick()
        {
            if(expandCollapseBtn.src.search('collapse') !=-1)
            {
                mainHolder.style.height = "30px";
                content.style.display = "none";
            }
            else
            {
                mainHolder.style.height = heightValue + "px";
            }
        }

        function transitionEndHandler()
        {
            if(expandCollapseBtn.src.search('collapse') !=-1)
            {
                expandCollapseBtn.src = "images/expand1.png";
            }
            else{
                expandCollapseBtn.src = "images/collapse1.png";
                content.style.display = "block";
            }
        }

        </script>
```

Comment: Multiple elements with the same id attribute is not valid HTML. Either use unique ids or use classes.

Comment: You realise the inherent singular of the selector `getElementById()` as opposed to, for example, `getElementsByClassName()` and `getElementsByTagName()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `mainHolder` elements like this:

```
<div class="mainHolder">...</div>
```

And then `addEventListener`s to each element like this:

```
var mainHolderElements = getElementsByClassName('mainHolder');

for (var i = 0, length = mainHolderElements.length; i < length; i++) {
    mainHolderElements[i].addEventListener(...);
}
```

Comment: Hi if I do the above (and add var infront of mainHolderElements) my css doesnt seem to be valid and nothing collapses

Answer (score 0):

There can be only one element with an id.

Change your id's to a class and select elements via the class.  As in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3887663/498699