# How to select specific className with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small problem with selecting class with Javascript. Here is my part of the code:

```
getComputedStyle(e).className && "car" !== e.tagName && c.addInlineStyle(e, "background-color:#fff"), c.addInlineStyle(e, n)
```

What I am trying to achieve is select this `car` class with `className`

Can somebody try to help me with this?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.car')` or `$('.car')`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select element by and classname in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3887619/select-element-by-and-classname-in-javascript)

Comment: Are you trying to select elements that are members of a given class or CSS rulesets that use a given class in a selector? Or something else? Your code is *very* confusing. What is `e`? What is `c`?

Comment: Assuming that `e` is a HTMLElement: 1) `getComputedStyle(e)` won't have a property `className`, and 2) its `tagName` property probably won't be `car` (because there's no such HTML element as `<car>`). Also, correct me if I'm wrong, it looks like you're  using `&&` as both a logical operator, and a substitute for an `if` statement. Which serves little purpose other than making it harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `document.getElementsByClassName("car")` to get the collection of all elements in the document with the specified class name (in this case, car), as a NodeList object.
This NodeList object represents a collection of nodes. The nodes can be accessed by index numbers which start at 0.